# React validate input

Tags: reactjs

I use material ui Dashboard for my application and I would like to set up the validation on my fields.

How to put an error message if I fields is empty during the sending of the form and to underline the field in red?

Here is an example input :

```
<CustomInput
    labelText={<FormattedMessage id="LoginTemplate.email" defaultMessage="Email"/>}
    id="email"
    formControlProps={{fullWidth: true}}
    inputProps={{
         onChange:this.handleChange,
         type:"email",
         name:"email",
         value:authentification.email,
         error:authentification.email == "" ? true : false,
         endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="end">
               <Email className={classes.inputIconsColor}/>
               </InputAdornment>
         )
    }}
/>
```

Thanks you for your help

Comment: I suggest that you pass a prop to CustomInput indicating whether a warning should be shown. 
In CustomInput Class, you should attach a css className which for example, underline the field in red, dynamically according to whether a warning should be shown.

Comment: It would be possible to have an example